# Unable to Rename Copied Files via Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file

I am trying to create a .BAT script that will read a list of file locations from a CSV (in column 1) and then find that file in a directory and copy it to a new folder giving it the name specified in column 2 of the CSV file.

The CSV looks like:

```
U:\source\OHSVols180\A100\B100\C107\F109.DOC,file1
U:\source\OHSVols180\A100\B100\C110\F152.PDF,file2
```

The .BAT file below currently works in that it accesses the CSV field 1 and copies the file to the new folder. My question is how do I manage to also rename the copied file as per column 2 in the CSV? It can keep the same file extension as previously listed in column 1. At the moment he files are named as originally F109.DOC and F152.PDF but I want them to be called file1.DOC and file2.PDF.

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%L in (U:\ExportList.csv) do copy "%%L" U:\Exported\
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Not sure how to reference the second part of the CSV and what code to put to rename the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%L in (U:\ExportList.csv) do copy "%%L" "U:\Exported\%%M%%~xL"
```

Where `%%M` is the second token requested (the second field will use the next letter after the `L` used as replaceable parameter) and `%%~xL` is the extension of the file being referenced by `%%L`

Comment: Works like a dream thanks have a niffty little file copying program now! I understand the tokens part 1,2 and that you just use the next letter in the alphabet for the next column. Just out of interest can you explain what the %%M%%~xL part means?

Comment: @83dons, it is included in the answer. You can execute `for /?` from command line to get the full list of available modifiers.

Comment: Ah yes apologies thanks for the solution I'v spent a day and half trying to work that out!

Comment: One extra question I have which is an add-on to the above which people may be interested in - hence no new topic.

It would be more streamlined if I could pull the file location and file name from a two column access table as this is where it resides. The Access database is called 'Export_Staff_Records.accdb' and the table called 'GENISYS_List_2'. This would allow me to cut out the part where I have to export a CSV from Access. I am not sure if Access tables can be used as the lookup source and how you would reference it in the query above. Thanks again.